# Count does not work when using index to access list

Tags: python, list, count

I am trying to count the instances of "1" appearing in a list. When I used index to access the elements in the list and implement a counter, the total number of count is always 1.

However, when I used the normal "for" iterations, the count actually works. Could anyone enlighten me?

Here's a snippet of what DOES NOT work:

```
for entry in range(len(nums)):
    count = counts = 0
    if nums[entry] == 1:
        count = count + 1
        print(count)
```

Here's a snippet of what works:

```
for num in nums:
    if num == 1:
        counts = counts + 1
```

Comment: Debugger could have solved this easily

Comment: Move ```count = counts = 0``` outside the loop

Comment: How about `nums.count(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you define the counter inside the for-loop and thus it gets reset to 0 in each iteration.

---

Just make sure to define the counter outside of the for loop

```
count = 0
for entry in range(len(nums)):
    if nums[entry] == 1:
        count = count + 1
        print(count)
```